# Teacher as a way of addressing

Tags: greetings

Can we use the word ***teacher*** as a form of address to our teacher?
As in "Excuse me, teacher! Can I ask a question"
I've heard different forms of address like *sir, or Mr. Connor, ...*
Doesn't calling your teacher "teacher" sound weird or maybe not appropriate?

Comment: I think the word is *professor* in most cases.

Comment: @Subjunctive what if the student is studying in first grade?!

Comment: Haha, that's far-fetched. In that case kids are allowed to say *Mr./Mrs.*

Comment: @Subjunctive little kids regularly call their teachers "teacher"... But I'm pretty sure that stops by the time they hit middle school. I hear ELL people (adults) say it all the time and, I'll admit, it's a pet peeve... something I don't like at all.

Comment: I agree with Catija: it sounds like something that little kids say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question is motivated by wanting to show **appropriate respect**.

From my experience, addressing the person who teaches your classes as **teacher** is usually used by the **very young** or those **learning English**. I assume the latter use it since they believe it is a **title**, which it is not in **English based countries** but may be considered as such in **other cultures**.

Usually a surname preceeded by **Mr.**, **Mrs.**, **Ms.** (AmE) or **Miss** is most appropiate inside and outside a **university** setting. **Miss** is used regardless of martial status in BrE during nursery.

**In university**, **Professor** is appropriate for those in that position. If a higher title is involved then **Dean**, **Provost**, **President**, etc. followed by a surname should be used.

During examinations, **Proctor** can be used without loss of respect or understanding.

I have always used Mr., Mrs., Ms. with the appropriate surname even when a **given name** was offered.

[Addition]
Having said all this, it has not been **unheard of** for certain teenagers to have used the salutation

> **Yo Teach!**

as shorthand for

> Hello Mrs. Corbett. How are you today?

Comment: Generally, I'd use titles like Mr., Mrs, Miss, and Ms with a last name or a full name (e.g., Mr. Johnson or Mr. Paul Johnson), but not just with a first name (e.g, Mr, Paul) or alone (e.g, Hello, Mr.). However, I hear people use them alone, with no full name or last name (You're wrong, Mr.!) in a slightly angry way or a humorous way, and with a first name (Mr. Paul) in a humorous way. What do you think?

Comment: If the teacher's **full name** is Paul Smith, using **Mr. Smith** would be used by a native speaker, **Mr. Paul** would not. A student **should never** address their teacher as simply **Mr.**, it would be disrespectful. **You're wrong Mr.!** could be used (in the way that you suggest) **among peers** or by a **teacher-to -student** but should not be used by a student to a teacher. BTW, addressing by **only using surnames** is used among peers or teacher-to-students in **public** (BrE) school settings.

Comment: What about outside the school context? I remember in the TV show 'Friends' when Ross and Rachel got married drunk, they called each other Mr. Ross and Mrs. Rachel (first names only). Is it the way you use them in a humorous way or is it just because they were drunk?!

Comment: They were drunk and that's why **Mr. / Mrs.** ***first-name*** is humorous in contrast the usual surname.  A possible subtext is also that Rachel had an independent character and by not using Ross' surname it showed her continued independence.  What does happen (in real life) is the groom might look at his bride and say "Hello **Mrs.** ***groom's surname*** " since it will be the first time she has been addressed that way (assuming she has taken on her husband's name).

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? Sure, the ability for it to be done is there.

Is it likely to be effective? Likely not as most teachers on their first day introduce themselves with a form of address to be used. Thus, I would refrain from doing it but I could imagine it being done infrequently.